# I need to find a point where a circumference intersects an ellipse.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I need to find a point where a circumference intersects an ellipse.

The equation of ellipse is
$$\frac{(x-x_{1})^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-y_{1})^2}{b^2}=1$$
and the equation of circumference is
$$(x-x_{0})^2+(y-y_{0})^2=r^2$$
where $(x_{0},y_{0})$ and $(x_{1},y_{1})$ are the centers of the circumference and of the ellipse respectively.

I've been trying to find $(x, y)$ of intersection using these formula's above, but stuck.

If someone already solve this problem Please help.

Comment: Use the equation for the circle to find $x$ expressed in terms of $y$. Insert into the ellipse equation. You'll get a fourth degree equation unless you're lucky with the coefficients in some way, but that's as should be expected, since a circle and an ellipse may intersect up to four times.

Comment: Converting to Polar coordinates might help.

Comment: Why does the edit change the notation of the $r^2$, etc? Seems obtuse to me.

Comment: In any case, if one insists on doing this as written, Drug, it's just a really gross substitution problem. Solve one equation for $x$ or $y$, shove it into the other, and hack away. Qwerty's suggestion will be much nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Arthur's comment, we initially obtain (from the equation of the circle)
$$x = x_0 \pm \sqrt{r^2 - (y - y_0)^2}.$$

Substituting this/these value(s) for $x$ in the equation for the ellipse, we get
$$\dfrac{\left((x_0 \pm \sqrt{r^2 - (y - y_0)^2}) - x_1\right)^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{(y - y_1)^2}{b^2} = 1.$$

Now, I make the substitutions
$$A = x_0$$
$$B = x_1$$
$$C = y_0$$
$$D = y_1$$
so that the last equation above takes the form:
$$\dfrac{\left((A \pm \sqrt{r^2 - (y - C)^2}) - B\right)^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{(y - D)^2}{b^2} = 1.$$

At this point, why not ask for help from [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)?  The WolframAlpha computation for $y$ in
$$\dfrac{\left((A - \sqrt{r^2 - (y - C)^2}) - B\right)^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{(y - D)^2}{b^2} = 1.$$
is [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20((A%20-%20(r%5E2%20-%20(y%20-%20C)%5E2)%5E(1%2F2))%20-%20B)%5E2%2F(a%5E2)%20%2B%20((y%20-%20D)%5E2)%2F(b%5E2)%20%3D%201%20for%20y).
The WolframAlpha computation for $y$ in
$$\dfrac{\left((A + \sqrt{r^2 - (y - C)^2}) - B\right)^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{(y - D)^2}{b^2} = 1.$$
is [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20((A%20%2B%20(r%5E2%20-%20(y%20-%20C)%5E2)%5E(1%2F2))%20-%20B)%5E2%2F(a%5E2)%20%2B%20((y%20-%20D)%5E2)%2F(b%5E2)%20%3D%201%20for%20y).

Afterwards, substitute the values for $y$ obtained by WolframAlpha into the very first equation above, to get the corresponding values for $x$.  You know the drill.